# How to get values from GORM in map format?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve a list of elements, for example:

User.findByCompany(company)

in map mode? Like this [companyName : user, companyName : user2...]

I am doing this using each but idk if there is something that can be done at the data retrieval stage in order to avoid to iterate the same thing twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy instead of each

```
User.findAll().groupBy{it.company}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit long winded but if you specify individual fields in an [executeQuery](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) you'll get a list of maps e.g.

```
User.executeQuery( select u.username, u.whatever from User u where u.company =?, ['aCompany' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findByCompany(company)*.properties
```

This will perform a spread and put the results in list